# HTML5 How to replace WebAudio API for Internet Explorer for javascript games?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-audio, web-audio-api, soundmanager2

I'm new with audio in html.  I found some nice examples for little javascript games.  Want I try to load the games in Internet Explorer, I got : "Web api audio is not supported in this browser".

I found this site : http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api  and look like Internet Explorer doesn't support it.

I found also SoundManager 2 that seem to work on all browsers.

My question, is there is a way to detect if the browser support WebApiAudio and offering a fallback if is not supported ?

I want to be able to offer the same functionality on all differents browsers, but I have no idea how to do that at this point.

One nice feature is able to play multiple sounds in the same time with ajustable volume sound (like explosions).

I want to create a helloworld that I could run on PC, Mac, Android and Ipad.  Is it possible ?

thanks a lot for my multiple questions.

I check this demo  :http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/MoonWarriors_-_Cocos2d-JS_Showcase   the sound works fine in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer there is only music, not sound effects

Comment: There is no polyfill for the Web Audio API.  However, if you're just playing back pre-recorded sounds as-is, you don't actually need the Web Audio API.  You can use something like jPlayer or SoundManager 2 to play back your sounds, both of which have automatic fallback.

Comment: Pretty sure Modernizr has a test for that.

Comment: SoundJS  same to be a good choice ?  http://createjs.com/#!/Demos/SoundJS/Audio-Test-Suite

Answer (score 9):

> My question, is there is a way to detect if the browser support
>   WebApiAudio and offering a fallback if is not supported ?

---

```
"use strict"



function audioContextCheck() {
    if (typeof AudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new AudioContext();
    } else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new webkitAudioContext();
    } else if (typeof mozAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new mozAudioContext();
    } else {

       // Do stuff with soundmanager or something else if Web Audio API is not supported




    }
}
var audioContext = audioContextCheck();
```