# AudioContext not loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, web, internet-explorer-11, audiocontext

I am using a visualiser that uses **AudioContext** to get frequency data. It doesn't work in Internet explorer.

A previous Stack Overflow question was somewhat relevant:

[HTML5 How to replace WebAudio API for Internet Explorer for javascript games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708341/html5-how-to-replace-webaudio-api-for-internet-explorer-for-javascript-games)

So, I am using the following code to get the AudioContext

```
function audioContextCheck() 
{
if (typeof window.AudioContext !== "undefined") {
    console.log('AudioContext');
    return new window.AudioContext();
} else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== "undefined") {
    console.log('webkitAudioContext');
    return new window.webkitAudioContext();
} else if (typeof window.mozAudioContext !== "undefined") {
    console.log('mozAudioContext');
    return new window.mozAudioContext();
} else {
   console.log('NONE OF THEM!');
}
}
```

The console returns **'NONE OF THEM'**, meaning that Internet Explorer (version 11) is unable to load any of the audio thingies.

Microsofts own doccumentation refers to AudioContext():
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn954795(v=vs.85).aspx

I am very confused, am I missing something?

Comment: I am finding results of IE not supporting certain Audio features, but this was from 2013. Surely it is supported now?

Comment: The documentation you link to is only valid for the Edge browser, IIUC, not IE11.